# Database error in classic ASP application

Tags: asp-classic, oledb

I have a classic ASP app which connects to an access database, I receive the following error when I try to access a page which connects to the database:

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005'

[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]General error Unable to open registry key 'Temporary (volatile) Jet DSN for process 0x1b48 Thread 0x1970 DBC 0x1948024 Jet'.

/gasket.inc, line 24
```

Here is my gasket.inc file:

```
<%
'include file for gasket table database object


'Dimension variables
Dim adoConG         'Database Connection Variable
Dim strConG     'Holds the Database driver and the path and name of the database
Dim rsGasket        'Database Recordset Variable
Dim strAccessDBG    'Holds the Access Database Name
Dim strSQLG         'Database query sring


'Initialise the strAccessDB variable with the name of the Access Database
strAccessDBG = "\\MyServer\databases\gaskets\gaskets.mdb"

'Create a connection object
Set adoConG = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

'Database connection info and driver
strConG = "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};uid=admin;pwd=; DBQ=" & strAccessDBG

'Set an active connection to the Connection object
'adoConG.Open "DSN=Gaskets"
adoConG.Open strConG

'Create a recordset object
Set rsGasket = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")


%>
```

Does that admin user require permission to access the database? Or am I missing something else which is obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a UID/PWD for this, that would have to match an account that was used to lock the database, or a machine/domain account that will have write to/lock permissions to the db. Also, keep in mind that classic ASP is running under the IUSR_ account by default - sometimes this account must have write access to the directory/file containing the Access db.

Comment: The problem is, the database is on another server to my IIS, and IUSR_ is a local account isnt it?

Comment: Yes - IUSR is local to the machine. If you're accessing a remote access db, they your connection string would need to reflect an account that was available on that machine.

Comment: So, in my example, that would be "admin" ? Otherwise how would I specify that in the connection string?

Comment: uid=machinename\username or uid=username valid on that machine. Impersonation on Classic ASP is a challenge at best. If you can use a System.DSN that you can set up on both your machine and the other machine, it might be an easier route.